# INSERT INTO SELECT FROM information_schema.processlist.info inside trigger bringing back INSERT query not original query

Tags: trigger, information-schema

I have a trigger on a table that needs to get the Querytext that caused the trigger, Using a similar syntax as the following

```
BEFORE INSERT 
... 
INSERT INTO 
...
SELECT information_schema.processlist.info 
WHERE processlist.ID = CONNECTION_ID()
```

...but the above example is returning the INSERT INTO SELECT not the original query.

Comment: "*Any suggestions gratefully received*" - I would recommend updating your Post's Tags with which database system and version you're using.